# vb.net how to display Selected data from postgresql?

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

why is it even though i declared correctly the database name and its table, the error always saying  **TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions** is not exists, I just want that if the firstname and lastname exist in the database the record of that i search will show in the DataGridView1

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim firstname = firstnametextbox.Text.Trim()
        Dim lastname = lastnametextbox.Text.Trim()
        Try
            Using MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=contacttracing;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=*****;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=*****;password=*****;"),
                    cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT firstname= '" & firstname & "', lastname= '" & lastname & "' FROM TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions ", MyCon)
                MyCon.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
```

Here is my postgresql tree

[image]

this is the error i get

[image]

UPDATE

ive tried this also

```
Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT firstname= '" & firstname & "', lastname= '" & lastname & "' FROM public.TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions ", MyCon)
```

it didnt work also...

Comment: Does it make a difference to fully qualify the table name? `FROM public.TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions`

Comment: Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT firstname= '" & firstname & "', lastname= '" & lastname & "' FROM public.TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions ", MyCon) , same error, it didnt work mr @NateBarbettini

Comment: I've never seen anyone arrange for SQL injection by allowing variable column aliases before..

Comment: do you know what is the proper way to do what i want? i am having trouble in query mr @CaiusJard

Comment: My first thought would be to try `"SELECT * FROM ""TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions"" "` - I suspect the table name might be case sensitive looking at the presentation in the query tool screenshot. If you right click it in your query tool and choose something like "select all rows" (i never used that query tool, but usually such tools have an option to right click a table name and choose to have it open a new query window prepopulated with a query that selects some data) what does the query look like that the tool generates?

Comment: SELECT * FROM public."TracingApp_tremployeesuppliershousememberssubmittedrecords"
ORDER BY id ASC  @CaiusJard this is the result

Comment: Note: use parameters, the current way you have it is grounds for SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to surround the table name in quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM ""TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions"" "
```

`""` being what one uses to get a single `"` into a VB string

I suggest this because I'm aware that PG converts all non quoted table names to lowercase (as can be seen in your "relation does not exist" error message) but the query tool tree shows that some letters in the table names are upper case, so I suspect the table names were created as case sensitive, and `TracingApp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions` is different to `tracingapp_fmemployeesuppliersfeedbackquestions`

It might be less annoying for you to change your table names, if no other app is using the database, so you don't have to fill your VB strings up with lots of `""`